# Compare two sheets in terms of cell colour

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets which have the same data, but one is old data and one updated... Each Sheet has different columns with cells which have colours affiliated with each and a value. My issue is finding a way of comparing the two sheets in terms of the colours so need to capture what has changed for example column 2 ID 2113 changed its colour from amber to green, or from green to red etc etc...

I tried putting the two into arrays however i found out it doesn't capture the format, which is all I need, I have formulas to capture the value data change...

This is what I have so far, any ideas how to take this forward?
Are multidimentional arrays the way forward to solve this?

**Combine sheet = the new data (updated)
Old Data = the old data**

**There are 19 columns, however its only Columns H-S (8-19) which have the pricing**

```
    Sheets("Combine").Select

    Dim arrNewData()

    Dim intRows

    intRows = Sheets("Combine").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ReDim Preserve arrNewData(1 To intRows, 1 To 19)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrNewData, 1)

        For j = 1 To UBound(arrNewData, 2)

            arrNewData(i, j) = Sheets("Combine").Cells(i, j)

      Next

   Next

    '---------------------------------------

    Sheets("Old Data").Select

    Dim arrNewData()

    Dim intRows

    intRows = Sheets("Old Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ReDim Preserve arrNewData(1 To intRows, 1 To 19)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrNewData, 1)

        For j = 1 To UBound(arrNewData, 2)

            arrNewData(i, j) = Sheets("Old Data").Cells(i, j)

      Next

   Next

   '----------------------------------------
```

--------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------
So I still need to get a reference to the row using the first column A.. as that contains an ID which I can then use the two arrays together to compare..

I also need to make the array size dynamic thus introducing **intRows**

Apparently a zero based array is better? but not sure how to define it?

```
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim oldSheet As Worksheet

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine")
Set oldSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data")

intRowsNew = newSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
intRowsOld = oldSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim newColourArray()
ReDim Preserve newColourArray(1 To intRowsNew, 7 To 19)

Dim oldColourArray()
ReDim Preserve oldColourArray(1 To intRowsOld, 7 To 19)

For r = 1 To intRowsNew ' this is the number of rows in your range

        newColourArray(r, 7) = newSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value
        oldColourArray(r, 7) = oldSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value

        Debug.Print "New is " & newColourArray(r, 7) & ", " & _
                    "Old is " & oldColourArray(r, 7)

    For c = 8 To 19

        newColourArray(r, c) = newSheet.Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex
        oldColourArray(r, c) = oldSheet.Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex

        Debug.Print "New is " & newColourArray(r, c) & ", " & _
                    "Old is " & oldColourArray(r, c)

    Next

Next
```

Comment: If all you need is the color.  than pass the color index into an array. `arrNewData(i, j) = Sheets("Old Data").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks for that. In my brain it clicked that you could use an array(i,j) which matches the `cells(x,y)` format - don't know how I overlooked that before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create multidimensional arrays - indeed, if you're wanting to read the Value from a large number of cells, a variant array is a good way to do it 
        Dim arrNewData As Variantas you don't need to loop through cells. So your code could be shortened to:

```
    dim arrOldData as Variant
    arrNewData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine").UsedRange.Value
    arrOldData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data").UsedRange.Value
```

However, the Value is no use to you, as you want the ColorIndex (or Color) of each cell's Font or Interior property (depending on whether you're testing font or fill colour). You, therefore, must run a loop.

Given the loop is unavoidable, I wouldn't bother reading the ColorIndex into an array and then looping through that array to test it. In effect you're looping through the same data twice. So I'd probably go for the following:

```
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oldSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newColorIndex As Integer
    Dim oldColorIndex As Integer        
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine")
    Set oldSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Old Data")

    For r = 1 To 30 ' this is the number of rows in your range
        For c = 8 To 19
            newColorIndex = newSheet.Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex
            oldColorIndex = oldSheet.Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex
            Debug.Print "New ColorIndex is " & newColorIndex & ", " & _
                        "Old ColorIndex is " & oldColorIndex
        Next
    Next
```

**Edit: The array version**

```
    Dim newColourArray(29, 11) ' using zero-based array, adjust if you wish
    Dim oldColourArray(29, 11) ' using zero-based array, adjust if you wish

    For r = 1 To 30 ' this is the number of rows in your range
        For c = 8 To 19
            newColourArray(r - 1, c - 8) = newSheet.Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex
            oldColourArray(r - 1, c - 8) = oldSheet.Cells(r, c).Font.ColorIndex
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: The porblem is that I need to compare the two arrays together... using a vlookup solution matching each entry together and checking if the colours have been changed etc..

Comment: That's no problem. If you need two arrays for other tasks then simply adjust the code as I've added in my edit.

Comment: Hi. Having some issues with your solution... i get some errors with regards to the array size, as it needs to be in proportion to how many cells are present. Please see what ive done above.

Comment: What's the error and what line does it occur on? Also, check your two worksheet UsedRanges are the same size.